# Transparent background for all figures in knitr Rmd

Tags: r, knitr

How can I set up a transparent background for all of my figures, both `base` and `ggplot2`, in `Rmd` file? My current setup is quite simple. The relevant header part is:

```
---
...
output:
    powerpoint_presentation:
        reference_doc: template.pptx
–-
```

and the `knitr` setup is as follows:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE, results='markup')
options(width=80, show.signif.stars=FALSE)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I have found the solution. The `knitr` setup should include:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE, results='markup')

# set transparent background in base
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev.args=list(bg='transparent'))

# set transparent background in ggplot
ggplot2::theme_set(ggplot2::theme_bw(base_size=12))
ggplot2::theme_update(panel.background=ggplot2::element_blank(),
    plot.background=ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.background=ggplot2::element_blank())

options(width=80, show.signif.stars=FALSE)
```
````